# Active Directory Authentication javascript files NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have implemented authentication with Active Directory username. Once logged in I have no issues accessing mvc controllers and operations.

Problem is I am getting unauthorized 401 access to javascript files once I am logged in. Do I have to set up specific scopes for this?

[image]

Comment: What if you manually request those files throught your browser?

Comment: 401 unauthorised request default Microsoft error screen

Comment: Have you removed IIS_IUSR permissions from that folder?

Comment: Do you mean in web config?

Comment: I mean in the file system